# Karate - Can't print values from the response (array of JSON objects)

Tags: arrays, json, karate

I have a test in Karate where the response is an array of JSON objects, all of them include a key called id. I need to print all those values but I can't figure out how.

I can print a single value by **'And print response[0].id'**
but I can't make it work for all the id.

I've tried:

**print each response.id**

**print each response..id**

Answer (score 1):

Please split into 2 steps. This below is using JsonPath: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#get

```
* def temp = $response[*].id
* print temp
```

This may work (pure JavaScript):

```
* print response.map(x => x.id)
```

For completeness, you can do this:

```
* print karate.jsonPath(response, '$[*].id')
# or
* print karate.get('$response[*].id')
```